# Динамический массив структур (С)

Tags: структуры, динамические-массивы, динамические-структуры

Кто-нибудь может объяснить как правильно объявить, инициализировать и работать с динамическим массивом структур в чистом C? Небольшой пример бы с заполнением этого массива и добавлением памяти... И как правильно редактировать созданную структуру в какой-либо функции? Как этот массив в нее правильно отправить?

Вообще, программа уже готова, но в ней используется статический массив. Задача: заменить его на динамический.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define MAX 150

struct avto {
    char brand_model[50];
    int year;
    float capacity;
    int horsepower;
    float mileage;
};

void init_list(struct avto avto_list[]);
int delete(int kolavt), list(int kolavt, struct avto avto_list[]), enter(int kolavt, struct avto avto_list[]), menu_select(void), find_free(struct avto avto_list[]), check_vvod(int kolpunkt);

int main(void) {
    char choice;
    struct avto avto_list[MAX], avto_list2[MAX], help;
    help.brand_model[0] = '/0';

    int kolavt = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    init_list(avto_list); /* инициализация массива структур */
    init_list(avto_list2);
    for (;;) {
        choice = menu_select();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1: kolavt = enter(kolavt, avto_list);
            break;
        case 2: kolavt = delete(kolavt, avto_list);
            break;
        case 3: list(kolavt, avto_list);
            break;
        case 4: sort_list(kolavt, avto_list, help, avto_list2);
            break;
        case 5: exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/*Проверка ввода целочисленных значений*/
int check_vvod(int kolpunkt) {
    int vvod = 0;
    char c = 0;
    while ((scanf_s("%d%c", &vvod, &c, 1) != 2) || (vvod < 1) || (vvod > kolpunkt) || (c != '\n')) {
        printf("Введенное значение некорректно! Попробуйте еще: ");
        if (c != '\n') while (getchar() != '\n');
        c = 0;
    }
    return vvod;
}

/*Проверка ввода дробных значений*/
float check_vvod2(float value) {
    float vvod = 0;
    char c = 0;
    while ((scanf_s("%f%c", &vvod, &c, 1) != 2) || (vvod < 1) || (vvod > value) || (c != '\n')) {
        printf("Введенное значение некорректно! Попробуйте еще: ");
        if (c != '\n') while (getchar() != '\n');
        c = 0;
    }
    return vvod;
}

/* Инициализация базы авто. */
void init_list(struct avto avto_list[])
{
    for (int t = 0; t < MAX; t++) avto_list[t].brand_model[0] = '\0';
}

/* Получения значения, выбранного пользователем в меню. */
int menu_select(void)
{
    system("cls");
    char s[20];
    int c;
    printf("1. Добавить автомобиль в базу\n");
    printf("2. Удалить автомобиль из базы\n");
    printf("3. Вывести список всех автомобилей\n");
    printf("4. Вывести список всех автомобилей, отсортированных по какому-либо полю\n");
    printf("5. Выход\n\nВвод: ");
    c = check_vvod(5);
    system("cls");
    return c;
}

/* Добавление автомобиля в базу. */
int enter(int kolavt, struct avto avto_list[]) {
    int slot;
    char s[80];

    slot = find_free(avto_list);

    if (slot == -1) {
        printf("\nСписок заполнен");
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    printf("Введите марку и модель: ");
    gets(avto_list[slot].brand_model);

    printf("Введите год выпуска: ");
    avto_list[slot].year = check_vvod(2020);
    //gets(avto_list[slot].year);

    printf("Введите объем двигателя: ");
    avto_list[slot].capacity = check_vvod2(30);
    //gets(avto_list[slot].capacity);

    printf("Введите количество лошадинных сил: ");
    avto_list[slot].horsepower = check_vvod(1000);
    //gets(avto_list[slot].horsepower);

    printf("Введите пробег: ");
    avto_list[slot].mileage = check_vvod2(10000000);
    //gets(avto_list[slot].mileage);

    kolavt++;
    return kolavt;
}

/* Поиск свободной структуры для занесения нового авто. */
int find_free(struct avto avto_list[])
{
    register int t;

    for (t = 0; avto_list[t].brand_model[0] && t < MAX; t++);

    if (t == MAX) return -1; /* свободных структур нет */
    return t;
}

/* Удаление адреса выбранного автомобиля из базы. */
int delete(int kolavt, struct avto avto_list[])
{
    if (kolavt == 0) {
        printf("Машин в базе нет!\n");
        system("pause");
    }
    else {
        int slot;
        printf("Введите № записи, которую хотите удалить: ");
        slot = check_vvod(kolavt);
        avto_list[slot - 1].brand_model[0] = '\0';
        if (slot < MAX) {
            for (int i = slot - 1; i < kolavt - 1; i++) {
                avto_list[i] = avto_list[i + 1];
            }
            avto_list[kolavt - 1].brand_model[0] = '\0';
        }
        kolavt--;
        return kolavt;
    }
}

/* Вывод списка автомобилей на экран. */
int list(int kolavt, struct avto avto_list[]) {
    float nalog = 0;
    if (kolavt <= 0) {
        printf("Машин в списке нет!");
    }
    else {
        for (int t = 0; t < kolavt; t++) {
            if (avto_list[t].brand_model[0]) {
                printf("%d автомобиль:\n", t + 1);
                printf("Марка, модель: %s\n", avto_list[t].brand_model);
                printf("Год выпуска: %i\n", avto_list[t].year);
                printf("Объем двигателя (м^3): %.2f\n", avto_list[t].capacity);
                printf("Количество л/с: %i\n", avto_list[t].horsepower);
                printf("Пробег (км): %.2f\n", avto_list[t].mileage);
                if (avto_list[t].horsepower < 100) {
                    nalog = avto_list[t].horsepower * 7;
                }
                else {
                    if ((avto_list[t].horsepower >= 100) && (avto_list[t].horsepower < 250)) {
                        nalog = avto_list[t].horsepower * 14;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (avto_list[t].horsepower >= 250) {
                            nalog = avto_list[t].horsepower * 30;
                        }
                    }
                }
                printf("Данная машина облагается налогом в размере: %.2f руб.\n\n", nalog);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");
}

/* Вывод списка с сортировкой на экран. */
int sort_list(int kolavt, struct avto avto_list[], struct avto help, struct avto avto_list2[]) {
    float nalog = 0;
    char res1[10];
    char res2[10];
    if (kolavt <= 0) {
        printf("Машин в списке нет!");
    }
    else {
        printf("Выберите поле, по которому будет произведена сортировка:\n\n1. Марка\n2. Год выпуска\n3. Объем двигателя\n4. Количество л/с\n5. Пробег\n6. Налог\n\nВвод: ");
        int menu = check_vvod(6);
        switch (menu) {
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            for (int i = 0; i <= kolavt; i++) {
                avto_list2[i] = avto_list[i];
            }
            printf("Список, отсортированный по марке автомобилей:\n\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < kolavt; i++)
                for (int j = kolavt - 1; j > i; j--)
                    if (strcmp(avto_list2[j].brand_model, avto_list2[j - 1].brand_model) < 0)
                    {
                        help = avto_list2[j];
                        avto_list2[j] = avto_list2[j - 1];
                        avto_list2[j - 1] = help;
                    }
            list(kolavt, avto_list2);
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            for (int i = 0; i <= kolavt; i++) {
                avto_list2[i] = avto_list[i];
            }
            printf("Список, отсортированный по году выпуска автомобилей:\n\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < kolavt; i++)
                for (int j = kolavt - 1; j > i; j--)
                    if (avto_list2[j].year < avto_list2[j - 1].year)
                    {
                        help = avto_list2[j];
                        avto_list2[j] = avto_list2[j - 1];
                        avto_list2[j - 1] = help;
                    }
            list(kolavt, avto_list2);
            break;
        case 3:
            system("cls");
            for (int i = 0; i < kolavt; i++) {
                avto_list2[i] = avto_list[i];
            }
            printf("Список, отсортированный по объему двигателя автомобилей:\n\n");
            for (int i = 0; i <= kolavt; i++)
                for (int j = kolavt - 1; j > i; j--)
                    if (avto_list2[i].capacity > avto_list2[j].capacity)
                    {
                        help = avto_list2[j];
                        avto_list2[j] = avto_list2[i];
                        avto_list2[i] = help;
                    }
            list(kolavt, avto_list2);
            break;
        case 4:
            system("cls");
            for (int i = 0; i < kolavt; i++) {
                avto_list2[i] = avto_list[i];
            }
            printf("Список, отсортированный по количеству л/с автомобиля:\n\n");
            for (int i = 0; i <= kolavt; i++)
                for (int j = kolavt - 1; j > i; j--)
                    if (avto_list2[i].horsepower > avto_list2[j].horsepower)
                    {
                        help = avto_list2[j];
                        avto_list2[j] = avto_list2[i];
                        avto_list2[i] = help;
                    }
            list(kolavt, avto_list2);
            break;
        case 5:
            system("cls");
            for (int i = 0; i <= kolavt; i++) {
                avto_list2[i] = avto_list[i];
            }
            printf("Список, отсортированный по пробегу автомобилей:\n\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < kolavt; i++)
                for (int j = kolavt - 1; j > i; j--)
                    if (avto_list2[i].mileage > avto_list2[j].mileage)
                    {
                        help = avto_list2[j];
                        avto_list2[j] = avto_list2[i];
                        avto_list2[i] = help;
                    }
            list(kolavt, avto_list2);
            break;
        case 6:
            system("cls");
            int nalog[MAX], nalog2;
            for (int i = 0; i <= kolavt; i++) {
                avto_list2[i] = avto_list[i];
                if (avto_list2[i].horsepower < 100) {
                    nalog[i] = avto_list2[i].horsepower * 7;
                }
                else {
                    if ((avto_list2[i].horsepower >= 100) && (avto_list[i].horsepower < 250)) {
                        nalog[i] = avto_list2[i].horsepower * 14;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (avto_list2[i].horsepower >= 250) {
                            nalog[i] = avto_list2[i].horsepower * 30;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("Список, отсортированный по размеру налога на автомобили:\n\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < kolavt; i++)
                for (int j = kolavt - 1; j > i; j--)
                    if (nalog[i] > nalog[j])
                    {
                        help = avto_list2[j];
                        avto_list2[j] = avto_list2[i];
                        avto_list2[i] = help;
                        nalog2 = nalog[j];
                        nalog[j] = nalog[i];
                        nalog[i] = nalog2;
                    }
            list(kolavt, avto_list2);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: struct *a = new struct[n]
a это массив
struct - это структура

Comment: Это С++, так не пойдет